# How to get the last few rows within each group in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

To get the last few rows of each group in DolphinDB, I would sort within each group by the temporal column in descending order and then use "select top n ...... from t context by x". Is there a way I can use code that essentially does "select last n .... from t context by x" to get the last few rows within each group directly without sorting?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `tail`

```
tail(obj, [n=1])
```

**obj** can be table name.

**n** last n number of rows to be returned.

find the documentation and examples in below link.

https://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?tail.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use "limit" with negative integers to select the last few observations after a "context by" clause

```
select * from t context by sym limit -5
```